# Datagridview only showing data in rows with async data access?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, datagridview

I'm somewhat confused right now

I have a method which sets all data of the cells per row in a Datagrid

the _context var is from entity framework

if I debug the method below like this, all data is set to the cells, but the data is not displayed

but as soon as I remove the comment on the first line in the method (it's just for testing, nowhere used) everything is working

so to me, it seems like there is some async access required to display the data

I searched on google but didn't find anything similar

it's really just the first line in the method which makes it working, and there's no reference to the justATest list anywhere

if I put the first line to the end of the method it doesn't work again, so it's working as long as there is an async access working before the for-each loop is debugged

and no I can't make everything async cause I had some errors, and everything works with synchronous data access

didn't write the code as well, I know it's a bad way to load the data in the datagridview

does anyone know whats wrong here?

best regards

EDIT: just found out that with that line commented out, every time a new iteration of the foreach-lopp starts the cells values of the previous row gets reset, don't how this is happening

```
private async Task InitializeProcessGroupsDgv()
    {
        //List<Test> justATest = await _context.Test.ToListAsync();

        List<ProcessGroup> processGroups =  _context.ProcessGroup.ToList();

        _view.Dgv_ProcessGroups.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _view.Dgv_ProcessGroups.DataSource = processGroups;

        // that the cheboxes for the locks can have 3 states
        ((DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)_view.Dgv_ProcessGroups.Columns[13]).ThreeState = true;
        ((DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)_view.Dgv_ProcessGroups.Columns[14]).ThreeState = true;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in _view.Dgv_ProcessGroups.Rows)
        {
            // set all TestOption-Checkboxes
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                if (_curTestRes != null)
                {
                    row.Cells[i + 1].Value = ((ProcessGroup)row.DataBoundItem).TestResourceProcessGroup.Where(x => x.TestResourceID == _curTestRes.ID).First().TestOptionTestRessourceProcessGroup.Where(x => x.TestOption.Name == row.Cells[i+1].OwningColumn.HeaderText).FirstOrDefault()?.Activated;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.Cells[i + 1].Value = false;
                }
            }

            var testResProcGr = ((ProcessGroup)row.DataBoundItem).TestResourceProcessGroup?
                .Where(trpg => trpg.TestResourceID == _curTestRes?.ID)?.SingleOrDefault();

            // load NrOfImpressions
            row.Cells[10].Value = testResProcGr?.NrOfImpressions;

            // set the Lock-CheckBoxes
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell dinCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[13];
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell astmCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[14];

            List<IntrusionBody> ibs = _context.IntrusionBody.Where(x => x.ProcessGroupID == ((ProcessGroup)row.DataBoundItem).ID).ToList();

            foreach (var item in ibs)
            {
                ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[12]).Items.Add(item);
            }

            ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[12]).ValueMember = "ID";
            ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[12]).DisplayMember = "Name";

            if (testResProcGr == null)
            {
                // if new TestRessource => disable lock checkboxes
                dinCell.ReadOnly = true;
                dinCell.Value = CheckState.Indeterminate;
                dinCell.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                dinCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray;

                astmCell.ReadOnly = true;
                astmCell.Value = CheckState.Indeterminate;
                astmCell.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                astmCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray;
            }
            else
            {
                // DIN
                if (testResProcGr.DINLocked == null)
                    dinCell.Value = CheckState.Indeterminate;
                else
                    dinCell.Value = (bool)testResProcGr.DINLocked ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked;

                // ASTM
                if (testResProcGr.ASTMLocked == null)
                    astmCell.Value = CheckState.Indeterminate;
                else
                    astmCell.Value = (bool)testResProcGr.ASTMLocked ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked;

                row.Cells[11].Value = testResProcGr.NrOfTestPerDay;
                ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[12]).Value = testResProcGr.IntrusionBody;
                row.Cells[15].Value = testResProcGr.Active;
                row.Cells[16].Value = testResProcGr.TestResourceProcessGroupCertification.Where(x => x.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).FirstOrDefault()?.DIN;
                row.Cells[17].Value = testResProcGr.TestResourceProcessGroupCertification.Where(x => x.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).FirstOrDefault()?.ASTM;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Marking a method as async when it does not have await operator does not make sense. The dummy await operator in the commented line just makes all other code that is after it execute synchronously. 
So the simplest way to make it work is removing the useless async modifier.

Comment: it doesn't matter if you remove the async from the method or not (of course i removed it when i tried it syncronously)
if you have a method marked as async but no await in it, the method will just run synchronously, so that's not the error
as i said, if i remove everythign async it doesn't work, if i just put some async statement inside method above the foreach-loop it works fine, that's my problem